# Form Post to new window with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, http-post

Currently I have a JavaScript method that submits a form POST and opens in a new window.  I want to rewrite this in AngularJS.

Here is the existing method.  The 3 parameters passed in just affect the post URL and some data values on the POST.

```
var login = function(postUrl, samlResponse, samlDomain){
    var form = $('<form></form>');
    form.attr('method', 'post');
    form.attr('action', postUrl);
    form.attr('target', '_blank');
    var field = $('<input></input>');
    field.attr('type', 'hidden');
    field.attr('name', samlResponse);
    field.attr('text-wrap','none');
    field.attr('value', 'response-value');
    form.append(field);
    var field2 = $('<input></input>');
    field2.attr('type', 'hidden');
    field2.attr('name', 'RelayState');
    field2.attr('value', samlDomain);
    form.append(field2);
    $(document.body).append(form);
    form.submit();
}
```

Here is my attempt to do this in AngularJS using $http

```
$scope.login = function(postUrl, samlResponse, samlDomain) {
    var tabWindowId = window.open('about:blank', '_blank');
    var data = {
        SAMLResponse: samlResponse,
        RelayState: samlDomain
    }
    $http.post(postUrl, data).then(function (response) {
        tabWindowId.location.href = response.headers('Location');
    });
}
```

I'm also getting the following error, which occurs because the site won't let me access the response.   I don't necessarily need access to the response, I just want to open it in a new window.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load {{postUrl}}. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:7631' is therefore not allowed access.
```

How should I accomplish what I'm trying to with AngularJS?

I've also considering adding the form to the HTML template but hiding it with ng-hidden.  Then I'd have to trigger the form submit from within my AngularJS controller somehow, which seems backwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up putting the login function exactly as is in my AngularJS controller.  Not too happy with this because I'm using jquery $(document.body).append(form).  But it was a quick solution, would like to see other answers.